# How can I use "add_fields" in django?

Tags: django, formset

I was reading django docs and found the [`add_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset) method.

The documentation says:

> "If you need to add additional fields to the formset this can be
>   easily accomplished. The formset base class provides an add_fields
>   method."

I want to use it but there is no example or explanation how
it can be used in views and templates. Can you provide me a small
example of using this method?

Comment: It's right there in the example they have added a field named 'my_field' in the second line in the add_field function.

Comment: @rahul tyagi, yeah, but I want an example of using in views and templates.

Comment: There's no special magic to using it in a view. For instance, if you have a `ModelFormSet`, `add_fields` could inspect `form.instance` to see if there's something special that needs to be done, i.e. show an additional checkbox for special Articles (or whatever your model is)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give a small example. 
The `models.py` looks like this,

```
from django.db import models


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`forms.py` looks like this,

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import BaseFormSet
from .models import Article


class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title']


class BaseArticleFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['body'] = forms.CharField()
```

`views.py` looks like this,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import formset_factory

from .forms import ArticleForm, BaseArticleFormSet

def home(request):
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, formset=BaseArticleFormSet, extra=3)
    context = dict()
    formset = ArticleFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            print(formset.cleaned_data)

    context['formset'] = formset

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Finally, `home.html` will look like this,

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

[image: This is the resulting output]

As you can see, the body field appears in templates but it is not included in the the Article model.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, that what 'm looking for.